# How to get table in html format using react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, .net-core

I have the following semantic-ui-react Table on jsx page

```
<Table id='myTable' celled selectable sortable headerRow={['Id', 'Name']} renderBodyRow={this.renderBody} tableData={list}  />
```

I need to put this table to html string in calling method

```
getHtmlTable() {
    var html = document.getElementById('myTable');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50000/api/table/",
        data: html,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success:function() {
        }
    });
}
```

And get it in the post method:

```
[HttpPost("html")]
public void GetData(string html)
{        
}
```

How can i get the table in html format? I found a .html() funciton in jQuery, but can't understand how to use it. I tried so:

```
<div className="htmlData">
    <Table id='myTable' celled selectable sortable headerRow={['Id', 'Name']} renderBodyRow={this.renderBody} tableData={list}  />
</div>

getHtmlTable() {
    var html = $('htmlData').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50000/api/table/",
        data: html,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success:function() {
        }
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your code is wrapped inside `componentDidMount`. `componentDidMount` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted.

[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
componentDidMount(){
  var html = document.getElementById('myTable').outerHTML
  this.getHtmlTable(html)
}
getHtmlTable(html) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50000/api/table/",
        data: html,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success:function() {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have proper selector to make it work:

```
var html = $('.htmlData').html();
```

Alternatively with plain JS you can use element's `outerHtml` property:

```
var html = document.querySelector("#myTable").outerHtml;
```

Comment: That helps to get html string in js, so when i call alert(html) the alert window with correct html string is shown. But it doesn't sent to GetData method - the income value is null

Comment: @Bashnia007, what does `HttpPost("html")` do? Try remove parameter, maybe it is some king of restriction?